# Convert date to string elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I want to get year from date in elastic search.My mapping is like -

```
"timeModified": 
{
   "type": "date",
    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
}
```

And my data store in elastic search is -

```
"timeModified": "2015-03-12T13:18:50.000+05:30"
```

I want to get year from the date.When I execute the below query -

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "left_field" : {
            "script" : {
                "inline": "doc.timeModified.value.substring(0, length)",
                "params": {
                    "length": 4
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It give me exception -

> "**No signature of method: java.lang.Long.substring() is applicable
>   for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [0,
>   4]\nPossible solutions: toString(), toString(), toString(),
>   toString(long, int)**"

If I have option to convert the field value date to string without change in my actual mapping type, I get the correct value. So please suggest how to convert in string in elastic search query.
Or if any other option to get year from date then also suggest.

Comment: Try `doc['timeModified'].date.year` to get the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is because the field value is a `Long` not a `String`. However, you can also access the `date` value directly by doing it like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "left_field" : {
            "script" : {
                "inline": "doc.timeModified.date.getYear()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The script is as simple as `doc['timeModified'].date.year`. Knowing that field is of type `date`, ES exposes the `.date` shortcut where things like `.year` can be used.